# Dynamic handling of CLI prompt based on caller

Tags: python, shell, automation, command-line-interface

Is it possible to have a CLI command which behaves dynamically when called from shell scripts/Ansible and when called from terminal ?

My use case is to add a warning followed by a prompt(y/n) for a certain command(used to perform a factory reset) but the prompt will break setup for users who are using this command through shell scripts or Ansible. Asking them to modify their scripts to automate the input to prompt does not seem to be very prudent. If there is any option to supply a default response to the prompt when it is called from a script(which might not be possible to detect), that should serve my purpose. The CLI is created in Python.

Sample use-case: In the first case, the user is using this command interactively and can input y/n. In the second case, a different user is using the same command but as part of a batch script, which will break unless something like `yes 'y' | app factory-reset` is used. I want the command to work without any such change with a default response, let's say 'y'.

Interactive mode

```bash
/usr/bin % app factory-reset
/usr/bin % WARNING: Performing a factory-reset will erase all user 
defined configurations and reset all settings to system default. 
Do you wish to continue ? (y/n)
y
/usr/bin % Starting factory reset . .
```

Batch mode

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1 before factory reset

app factory-reset

# Step 2 after factory reset
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If the CLI is a Python program, you could make the prompt as option to that program.

Comment: _to supply a default response to the prompt_  : I find your question confusing. On one point, you want to see a different prompt, and then you want to have a default respone to a certain prompt. These are two pretty different issues. If you need both, please ask two different questions.

Comment: @user1934428 I hope the latest edit clears the confusion, I don't have need for two prompts, I want to override the prompt if my command is called as part of a batch script.

Comment: So, basically, you want to find out, whether you are interactive or not, and if not interactive, provide the answer to your yes/no-prompt automatically? If this is correct, please be careful with the wording: You are not wanting to _override_ the prompt, but to _automatically answer_ to the prompt.